# Can I replace a word in a string using a for loop?

Tags: python, string

I want to replace poor with good

```
MyStr2 = "I am poor"
MyLis = MyStr2.split(" ")

for i in range(MyLis):
    if MyLis[i] == "poor":
        MyLis[i] = "Good"



a = " ".join(MyLis)
print(a)
```

But it shows a error:
*Traceback (most recent call last):
File "e:\codes\learning\String.py", line 32, in 
for i in range(MyLis):
TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer*

Comment: Change `range(MyLis)` to `range(len(MyLis))`.

Answer (score 2):

By using a dictionary, your code will be easily extensible for additional replacements. For your simple case:

```
MyStr2 = "I am poor"
d = {'poor': 'Good'}

print(' '.join(d.get(t, t) for t in MyStr2.split()))
```

**Output:**

```
I am Good
```

In this way you could add additional replacements to *d* without modifying anything else in the code

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the list of *words* and append each word which doesn't satisfy the criteria to a new string otherwise perform the replacement.

```
MyStr2 = "I am poor"
MyLis = MyStr2.split(" ")

myStr_new = ''
for word in MyLis:
    if word == "poor":
        myStr_new += "Good"
    else:
        myStr_new +=word

print(myStr_new)
```

In "comprehension form":

```
MyStr2 = "I am poor"
MyStr2_new = ' '.join("Good" if word == 'poor' else word for word in MyStr2.split(' '))

print(MyStr2_new)
```

Comment: You have written first *MyLis* and then in the for loop *MyList* in the first script.

Answer (score 1):

[`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) should be used with [`len(MyLis)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len), as others have said, as it expects an integer.

However, I'd rather do it the following way.

You can [**`enumerate`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) the indices of all the values in your sequence (`list`):

```
for index, value in enumerate(MyLis):
    if value == 'poor':
        MyLis[index] = 'Good'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `range()` is expecting an integer value and you’re giving it `MyLis` which is a list object.

You want to iterate over the *length* of your list, so you need to do `range(len(MyLis))` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
a="I am poor"
a1=a.split(" ")
for i in a1:
    if i=="poor":
        i="Good"
    print(i,end=" ")
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: We are using Split function to split the characters in a. And Storing it in A1. for  loop will take each word and store it as I. And then we are checking the word which we need to replace by using relational operator == atlast we will change that replacing word with a replaceable word by using assignment operator. Then print the words by using for Loop.

Comment: [edit] your answer, don't add explanations in comments.